# What is the optimum elevation angle for my 3000W heater?

Tags: thermodynamics, fan

In an empty room shaped like a cube with verticies of length a and at 20C starting temperature (homogeneously distributed), what is the optimum elevation angle, X, of my 3000W heater fan if it is placed in the corner of the room? The goal is to maximise the temperature of the room.

Questions:

- What is the optimum elevation angle of the heater, X?
- Is X dependent on a?

Please ask me for relevant details I'm missing out.

Additional details:

- Heat is evenly and continuously lost through the walls (@User58220)
- I do not care how warm it *feels*
- Time does not matter (assume T->infinity)

[image]

Comment: You need to specify data to fully define the following: (1) The *steady state* temperature will be set by the pathways that the 3000W heat leaks from the room: you need to know losses through the walls. (2) Is your goal to raise temperature in a short time, or is there no time limit? (3) If your goal is to make the room warm, then room temperature may not be a good measure. To give an example: in Summer, one part of our house is unbearably hot: the other end is comfortable and cool. The air temperature in both parts is *exactly the same* (to within 0.2C). The difference ...

Comment: ... is the different heat loadings one's body gets from the walls through radiation. The hot part of the house has a high ceiling with only small roof cavity, so that the hot ceiling heats only air near to it and does not affect air temp near the ground. But it is unbearable to sit under. The cool part of the house has a roof cavity and a cool ceiling. "Warmth" is defined by the total heat loading on one's body, and air temperature only partly defines this.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - you and I were thinking along exactly the same lines...

Comment: Many insights gained, cheers @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance

Comment: Given the constant energy input and no possibility of heat loss, why do you think there should be a maximum temperature?

Answer (score 2):

Your goal is to maximize the temperature of the room. I assume this is in steady state.

If your heater runs indefinitely, the steady state temperature will be the one where the heat loss through the walls / ceiling / floor / windows equals the heat input. You will achieve this by pointing the heater away from the surface with the greatest heat loss. For example, if you have windows they are likely to have the lowest thermal resistance to the outside - you would want to set up the air flow so the air is coolest near the window (and preferably you don't want the air to flow at all; that will slow down the cooling even more).

Without information about the relative thermal properties of the surfaces, one cannot say much more than this - just make the air move slowly so a cold layer on the walls stays there and can act as a "blanket". After that, the direction of the heater doesn't matter much.

Comment: this is a great insight cheers, I was actually expecting/hoping X to be presented by somebody as a model equation I can see what it is from your answer @Floris